# Почему не могу создать файл с webkitRequestFileSystem

Tags: javascript

Только сегодня узнал о том что на JavaScript'e оказывается можно все таки создавать файлы и пытаюсь это сделать в Хроме с помощью вот такого кода:

```
window.webkitRequestFileSystem(window.TEMPORARY, 1024*1024, function(fs) {
    fs.root.getFile('test.txt', {create: true}, function(fileEntry) {
        fileEntry.createWriter(function(fileWriter) {
            var builder = new window.WebKitBlobBuilder();
            builder.append('Some text');
            var blob = builder.getBlob('text/plain');
            fileWriter.write(blob);
        }, function() {});
    }, function() {});
}, function() {});
```

Но файл на хостинге не создается. На сайте [caniuse.com](https://caniuse.com/#feat=filesystem) пишет что это способ создать файл в sandboxed file system. Где эта "система-песочница" и можно ли все таки создавать на хостинге файлы с помощью JavaScript?

Comment: Очевидно что напрямую файлы создавать нельзя из за политики безопасности. Это лишь для создания файла в "песочнице" клиента. На хостинге вы его не создадите. Что такое песочница https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B0_(%D0%B1%D0%B5%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C)

Comment: Подтверждаю, JS не имеет доступа к файловой системе бекенда , иначе была бы ой какая дыра в безопасности.